# FTP over TLS/SSL in Linux without installing external package?

Tags: linux, ftp, suse, ftps

We have a non-root account on a Linux server, so it can not install package
we have to ftps to another machine in this server.

If I try this :

```
>ftp [machinName]
```

after inserting username, it shows the following error:

> 534 policy requires ssl ftp

how can I handle FTP over SSL without external package such as lftp, curl, ...

My Linux: SUSE Linux version 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most *nix servers come with some scripting language installed. PHP or Python have FTPS (FTP over TLS/SSL) functions.

So you can write a PHP/Python script for your FTPS task.

- PHP: [How to Send File over secure FTP SSL Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2851547/850848#2851799).
- Python: [FTPES - FTP over explicit TLS/SSL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5534830/850848)